# Why can't I show FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in populateViewHolder?

Tags: javascript, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

Although I have tried many things, I cannot fix it. I apply the methods with Alt + Enter, I make the necessary arrangements on the added classes, but I still did not get a smooth result.
Error code;

> Class 'Anonymous class derived from FirebaseRecyclerAdapter' must
> either be declared abstract or implement abstract method
> 'onBindViewHolder (VH, int, T)' in 'FirebaseRecyclerAdapter'

Activity.Java

```js
public class PlacesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mBlogList;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_places);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Global");
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);

        mBlogList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.placesRecyclerView);
        mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>firebaseRecyclerAdapter= new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>
                (Blog.class, R.layout.blog_row,BlogViewHolder.class,mDatabase) {


        protected void populateViewHolder(Blog model, BlogViewHolder viewHolder, int position){
            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());
             }


        };

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();;
        mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        View mView;
        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title)
        {
            TextView post_title = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }
        public void setDesc(String desc){
            TextView post_desc = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            post_desc.setText(desc);
        }
        public void setImage(Context ctx, String image)
        {
            ImageView post_image = (ImageView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
        }
    }

}
```

Blog.java

```js
public class Blog {
    private String title;
    private String desc;
    private String image;

    public Blog(String title, String desc, String image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public Blog(){

    }
}
```

[populateRecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugqJb.png)